# Can I travel to Croatia after being refused entry in 2018?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, denial-of-entry, croatia

I was refused entry to Croatia because I had only a single entrance Schengen visa in 2018. However, I received no refusal stamps or letter from the Croatian border control.

In June  2019, I managed to successfully travel to Schengen countries such as Spain, Portugal, France, Poland, Lithuania, Norway, Iceland, Luxembourg, and Belgium with a Schengen visa issued by Spain.

Question is: I still have a dream of one day visiting Dubrovnik. Will I be turned away at the border because I was previously refused entry, even if this time I obtain a valid Croatian visa or a multiple entry Schengen visa?

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity. If I have misstated anything, please revert it to your original text.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can travel to Croatia on your current Schengen Visa, your formal entry denial due to single entry visa will not affect a later entry because you did not violate any regulations.

Had you violated any regulation and been denied it would be a different matter but since that is not the case you are good to go.

As always however in these matters it’s always good to place a call to the visiting country’s border control agency and ask they are normally quite helpful albeit sometimes hard to get hold of

Comment: Yes could not agree more to recheck thank you so much , this is so helpfull.

Comment: @user96563 Email policija@mup.hr and pitanja@mup.hr. Start the message by "To the Border police" and ask your question in simple English. You should receive a reply, though mostly likely in Croatian